# Read and write lines n times

Tags: python

I have a text file that serves as an initiation file for a model. It looks like this:

```
foo1
foo2
bar, foo, yolo
1, 2, 3
foo3
foo4
```

Line 3 is the header and line 4 takes the values and both lines need to be repeated dependant on how big x is. Let's say x = 3. The lines below should not be overwritten, but moved down. The lines in front (foo1 & foo2) are dynamically generated, so there are not necessarily only two lines, thus I can't just access them by their index!

So my file should then look like this:

```
foo1
foo2
bar, foo, yolo
1, 2, 3
bar, foo, yolo
1, 2, 3
bar, foo, yolo
1, 2, 3
foo3
foo4
```

My idea so far:

```
initraw = open('fileX.txt', "r") #opening raw file for reading
initwrite= open('fileY.txt', "w") #opening file for writing
initline = initraw.readlines() #writing content of raw file into string

x = 3

for line in initline:
    initwrite.writelines(line,)
    if line.startswith('bar, foo, yolo'):
        for i in range(x):
            initwrite.writelines(initline[2])
            initwrite.writelines(initline[3])

initwrite.close() #closing file
initraw.close() #closing raw file
```

Any suggestion how to solve this? Right now, this looks like this:

```
foo1
foo2
bar, foo, yolo
bar, foo, yolo
1, 2, 3
bar, foo, yolo
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
foo3
foo4
```

So I need to skip the first line after "bar, foo, yolo".

Comment: won't this write the lines between the `bar` line and the `1, 2, 3` line?  You should just find the indices of the lines you want the new lines to come after and use `insert` to add them to `initline`.  (This is because `readlines` returns a `list` of strings, not a string)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh see my last edit...yes, you're right. But the number of lines before those lines I need to replicate is not fixed, so I need to use `startswith` unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
   x = 2
    lines = [[item] for item in initrow.split('\n')]
    lines[2:4] = lines[2:4] * x

    print lines
    #will output [['foo1'], ['foo2'], ['bar, foo, yolo'], ['1, 2, 3'], ['bar, foo, yolo'], ['1, 2, 3'], ['foo3'], ['foo4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
initraw = open('fileX.txt', "r") #opening raw file for reading
initwrite= open('fileY.txt', "w") #opening file for writing
initline = initraw.readlines() #writing content of raw file into string

i = 0
for line in initline:
    x = 3
    i =+ 1
    if line.startswith('bar, foo, yolo'):
        for x in range(0, x-1):
            initwrite.writelines(initline[i+1])
            initwrite.writelines(initline[i+2])
    initwrite.writelines(line)      
initwrite.close() #closing file
initraw.close() #closing raw file
```

Comment: I edited my post...figured out that misplaced 'continue' myself while you wrote your reply. Still, something is missing.

Comment: Edited, modified some lines in the code.  Outputs fine now.

Comment: another edit after a previous reply: the lines in front are dynamically generated, so the number of lines is random! So I can't access them by the index...sorry for not stating this immediately.

Comment: Edited once again, output should work for what you want.